# spring ibatis mysql intermittent asynchronous problem

Tags: java, mysql, spring, ibatis, mybatis

I'm using ibatis in spring to write to mysql.

I have an intermittent bug. On each cycle of a process I write two rows to the db. The next cycle I read in the rows from the previous cycle. Sometimes (one time in 30, sometimes more frequently, sometimes less) I only get back one row from the db.

I have turned off all caching I can think of. My sqlmap-config.xml just says:

```
<sqlMapConfig>
<settings enhancementEnabled="false" statementCachingEnabled="false" classInfoCacheEnabled="false"/>

<sqlMap resource="ibatis/model/cognitura_core.xml"/>
```

Is there some asynchrony, or else caching to spring or ibatis or the mysql driver that I'm missing?

Using spring 3.0.5, mybatis 2.3.5, mysql-connector-java 5.0.5

EDIT 1:

Could it be because I'm using a pool of connections (c3p0)? Is it possible the insert is still running when I'm reading. It's weird, though, I thought everything would be occuring synchronously unless I explicitly declared asynch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling SqlSession.commit() after the inserts? C3P0 asynchronously "closes" the connections, which may be calling commit under the covers. That could explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That sounds very promising.. I'm not sure what you mean by SqlSession.commit(). I'm calling the insert like so getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("insertIterationHistory",dataMap); - the template doesn't appear to have a commit method. Should I just annotate the method with @Transaction? I guess I don't really understand where the commit is supposed to take place. I thought each insert would auto-commit by default..

Comment: Hmmm.. I just read http://old.nabble.com/how-to-dusable-asynch-threads---td21196742.html adding weight to your asynchronous explanation. I think I'm just going to use a different connection pool that does things synchronously..

Comment: Sorry, misread that as MyBatis 3. The principle is the same. You need a transaction to get a DB commit, so adding the annotation should work, assuming you have a DataSourceTransactionManager configured and have something like <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> in your Spring config.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting similar behavior. This is what I'm doing. I have an old version of IBATIS I don't plan on upgrading. You can easily move this into a decorator.

```
SqlMapSession session = client.openSession();
try {
    try {
        session.startTransaction();
        // do work
        session.commitTransaction();
        // The transaction should be committed now, but it doesn't always happen.
        session.getCurrentConnection().commit(); // Commit again :/
    } finally {
        session.endTransaction();
    }
} finally {
    session.close(); // would be nice if it was 'AutoCloseable'
}
```